# android ActionBar Without extending ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android

I want to use `ActionBar` without extending `ActionBarActivity`, because I have already extended a `TabActivity`.
 can anyone please help ?

I have done something like this. in this I want to implement Action Bar

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

private TabHost myTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myTabHost=getTabHost();
```

Comment: `TabActivity` has been deprecated **for over four years**. Please use modern techniques for tabs, such as a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator.

Answer (score 0):

try my code. You will be able to have fragments with action bar and tabhost.

```
1) XML file for Activity:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>


2) Java code for Activity:

    public class CarsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements   YourFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener
    {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     _mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
     _mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
     //add your fragments here:
     _mTabHost.addTab(_mTabHost.newTabSpec("*UNIQE IDENTIFIER OF YOUR    FRAGMENT").setIndicator("*DISPLAY NAME ON TAB*"),
                YourFragment.class, null);
    }
    });
     @Override
     public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri)
      {}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getActionBar()` in `oncreate()` or if you want to create custom action bar then use code below.

```
    // Action Bar Customization
    ActionBar ab =act.getActionBar();

    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(act.getResources().getColor(color.ActionBar_bg));
    ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);

    //ab.setBackgroundDrawable(act.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header));
    ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // disables default title on
                                            // actionbar.
    ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); // enables custom view.
    ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); // hides app icon.
    ab.setTitle("");
    // Inflating Layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getActionBar()
            .getThemedContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View customActionBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);

    imgapplogo = (ImageView) customActionBar.findViewById(R.id.app_logo);
    img_back=(ImageView)customActionBar.findViewById(R.id.imgBack);
```